# Install MacTex on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install MacTex on MacOS El Capitan (10.11.6) using `brew cask install mactex` yet I get `Error: macOS Sierra or newer is required.`. Is there a way of using brew to install an older version? For context, I'm looking to install it to use manim (math graphic python library developped by 3Blue1Brown) and already have texlive2017 installed but it doesn't seem to work for manim.
Thanks for upcoming help!

Comment: See `http://tug.org/mactex/` (note that many have had strange problems with texlive and brew, I'm not a Mac user so never tried it). The MacTeX page tells you what to do if your Mac is too old.

Comment: For El Capitan, the latest MacTeX is the 2018 one, available at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/mactex/2018/

Comment: @lhf How can one match the MacTeX versions with Mac OS version?

Comment: @Karlo, unfortunately I didn’t find a table or anything like that in the MacTeX website. I had to do it by trial and error.