What is the last MacTeX distribution for macOS 10.13?
I've tried installing the 2023 and the 2022 distribution but after hours of downloading... it appeared that they are not compatible with macOS 10.13.
What is the last MacTeX distribution for macOS 10.13?
(And what is a link to this distribution?)

See also the comments in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526009/install-mactex-on-el-capitan

The MacTeX website should have a table for the last MacTeX distribution for each macOS version.

Older versions of the MacOS can still use the regular Unix installer available on the TUG web site:
https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html
This is a better solution than installing an older version of the MacTeX installer, since it will get you an up-to-date distribution.
